# Jenkins - Testing for Faiure

Tags: git, bash, shell, jenkins

In my Jenkins test (just shell), I want to check for the exist status of a command (in this case, it's the presence of the git remote):

```
git ls-remote some_remote
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
  git remote add some_remote some@gitrepo.git
fi
```

However, if remote doesn't exists it the first command returns non zero exit status and the test fails without going further.

Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```
git ls-remote some_remote || status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
  git remote add some_remote some@gitrepo.git
fi
```

This way, the first line will always return true, and you can still capture the status of ls-remote.

Answer (score 0):

grep config file for remote and take necessary action based on zero or non zero status of grep